# how to run js file in mongo using springs

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I use the following code to run a mongo script in js through spring data

```
ScriptOperations scriptOps = mongoOperation.scriptOps();

// Execute script directly
ExecutableMongoScript echoScript = new ExecutableMongoScript("function(x) { return x; }");
Object ob=scriptOps.execute(echoScript, "directly execute script");  
System.out.println(ob);

// Register script and call it later
scriptOps.register(new NamedMongoScript("runjs", "D:\\GSTR3\\gstr3b.1.a.js")); 
scriptOps.call("runjs", "execute script via name");
```

The "echoScript" run but "runjs" gives error:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "/10.144.113.138:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "ReferenceError: runjs is not defined :\n_funcs1@:1:24\n" , "code" : 139 , "codeName" : "JSInterpreterFailure"}
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:71)
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:110)
at com.mongodb.DB.eval(DB.java:358)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultScriptOperations$2.doInDB(DefaultScriptOperations.java:119)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:446)
... 2 more
```

But if i run the script normally by node.js, i get the result:

```
D:\GSTR3>node gstr3b.1.a.js
{ Gstin: '27AIXPT3280A1Z2',
  t_ival: 100003.78,
  t_iamt: 0,
  t_camt: 173520.1,
  t_samt: 173527.69999999998,
  t_itm_count: 33 }
D:\GSTR3>
```

Answer (score 0):

scriptOps.register takes ExecutableMongoScript as argument, syntax: scriptOps.register(ExecutableMongoScript arg0) and NamedMongoScript takes two arguments, syntax: NamedMongoScript(String name, ExecutableMongoScript script), it never takes a path of JavaScript.

So, what we can do is to run the .js script as a java processor and wait for its completion and get the output from its input stream.

```
try{
   String nodejsPath = "D:\\GSTR3\\gstr3b.1.a.js";
   String cmd = "node " + nodejsPath;
   Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
   pr.waitFor();
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```